# Two page templates that both render dynamically but share the same route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I have two custom page types that use dynamic routing, queried from Prismic CMS, service_page and about_page. I'm running into a problem in my express server custom routing however - if my servicePage route is listed first, the aboutPage wont render. But if its vice versa, the servicePage won't route but my aboutPages will. Is there a way to have two custom types with dynamic routes?  I understand I can add a prefix to them (services/:uid or about/:uid) but I'd really rather avoid that for company purposes.

```
server.get('/:uid', (req, res) => {
  const nextJsPage = '/servicePage';
  const queryParams = { uid: req.params.uid };
  app.render(req, res, nextJsPage, queryParams);
});
server.get('/:uid', (req, res) => {
  const nextJsPage = '/aboutPage';
  const queryParams = { uid: req.params.uid };
  app.render(req, res, nextJsPage, queryParams);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your purpose?
When using routing in general the first listed url that matches the url you requested will be displayed. You can't expect any other behavior. 
I don't think you can use Regex here if there is a difference between the ids (such as 9 digits vs. 2 digits for example), but you can try searching about it. Otherwise, you must use a prefix.